# Android: ListView background color anomaly

Tags: android, listview, colors, background, background-color

I have a problem on a ListView, practically the background color of the rows changes at random without being set by code.. I tried to invalidate the ListView, change visibility, remove all the children and recreate it, but nothing.

This is a screen of right color:
[right color](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/708/20130610105841.png/)

And this the wrong one:
[wrong color](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/20130610104737.png/)

The colors of the rows are set within the method getView according to their position, the blue color is given to specific rows and the same code that sets this color also changes the picture on the right.

I tried to debug the code and there are no errors in the assignment of color..

The piece of code that assigns the background color:

```
View v = _vi.inflate(R.layout.row_prodotto_generale, parent, false);

LinearLayout la = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutProdottoGenerale);
la.setBackgroundResource( ((position % 2) == 0) ? R.color.color_row_odd : R.color.color_row_even  );

final Prodotti c = (Prodotti)_data.get( position ); // Item in the row
if( c != null ) {
    // Set text label
    // Set text color to black
    // Set the plus image on the right

    if(Float.compare(c.getProdottoQta(), +0.0f) > 0) {
        // If the item has a specific field bigger than 0
        la.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_blue));
        // Set text color to white
        // Set the other image on the right
    }
}
```

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutProdottoGenerale"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowProdottoGeneraleNome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="180dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="@string/_nome_"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowProdottoGeneraleMarca"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="180dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="@string/_marca_"
            android:textColor="@color/color_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addProdotto"
            android:background="@color/color_white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/addProdotto"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/plus"
            android:src="@drawable/piu_blu" >
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Normally the blue background color is on the entire row, when the problem occurs only the background of the first child of "linearLayoutProdottoGenerale" change in blue.

The problem occurs randomly when i try to search an item, or when i click the image on the right of a row, or when i click on the top view the one above the search box (btw is a collapse view).
Also the problem occurs only on my Galaxy Tab 2, i tried also some smartphone (Nexus S, Galaxy Ace) and on emulators but here all works good.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else` clause:

```
if (Float.compare(c.getProdottoQta(), +0.0f) > 0) {
    // If the item has a specific field bigger than 0
    la.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar_blue));
    // Set text color to white
    // Set the other image on the right
}
else {
    la.setBackgroundResource( ((position % 2) == 0) ? R.color.color_row_odd : R.color.color_row_even  );
}
```

Comment: i tried it, if the row get blue color also the text label will change and the image too. And in no other part of code i use that color

Comment: You are setting it on your LinearLayout right? Seems like it would make sense for the whole row to change then. Hard to see what is going on. If I were you I would post your entire `getView()`, and `row_prodotto_generale.xml` so people can help more.

Comment: added it, hope to find a solution

Comment: I'm not sure if this is contributing to the problem but you should really be making use of `convertView` in `getView()`. (http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html) Additionally you should look into using a `ViewHolder` (http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)